# Azure DNS / Additional CNAME Records

Tags: azure

I have setup my websites in Azure with my domain which is mywebsite.azurewebsites.net then with my real domain www.mywebsite.com i've got that pointed at mywebsite.azurewebsites.net which works fine after setting up all the awverify domains etc.

What i need to do now thought is be able to setup domains like:

```
hello.mywesbite.com
world.mywesbite.com
test.mywesbite.com
one.mywesbite.com
```

and have them point to the same place but im having problems. If i go to azure add under manage domains add "one.azurewebsites.net" i get an error "Too many (2) hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is 1." so i've tried adding one.mywebsite.com to the list but i also get another error.

Is it now possible to add an endless amount of subdomains of mywebsite.com  which will point to the same place?

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: Azure website has that limit set due to *preview*. I am sure the limit will be removed after preview is over. I am not sure if the limit if different for different modes i.e. *shared* vs. *reserved* (worth checking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this partially working, i already had it configured as share.

I have now setup a wildcard CNAME record with my DNS provider so *.mywebsite.com points to mywebsite.azurewebsites.net - Which works, ONLY if i configure the same subdomain on the azure wide. So instead, i now point my wild card cname to wildcardsubdomain.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 1):

It seems your website is set as "FREE" and you can’t do custom domain for free thats why you are hitting this error. You can check it at websites > Scale page.

If you change websites to shared or reserved (using website > scale)  mode then you can add more custom domains. The Preview limit for Shared and Reserved is 100. Numbers could improve when it hits GA.